# render can't be use in react function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wonder why I can't use render in react's function. Below code has error. Any clue?

```
renderNewApplicants = (items) => {

    let new_applicants = items.filter(obj => 
        obj.applicants.result.is_new === true
    )

    render(){
        return( //map new_applicants here )
    }
 }
```

then somewhere else in jsx I do `{this.renderNewApplicants}`

Comment: you can not call `render` in this way.Use `setState` to update the state which will cll render for you. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1):

You can just return your JSX from your function remove the render function.

Render is only used in class component not in function component.

```
renderNewApplicants = (items) => {

  let new_applicants = items.filter(obj => 
    obj.applicants.result.is_new === true
  )

  return(<div> some markup here.</div>);

}
```

check the documentation here
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html